# How I can convert my web application to desktop application with same functionality using Node EJS

Tags: node.js, electron, ejs, desktop-application, electron-packager

I've web application build with EJS/jQuery/Bootstrap with Node js REST API.
Is it possible to create executable/installer for Windows operating system?

Without any 3rd-party software, it should look like native application, but HTML and EJS template engine.

Any ideas?

I probably need support of EJS in html view, but I need all features for EcmaScript5/CSS3.

I have used Electron Packager for creating exe for windows.but EJS  not supporting for dynamic data.

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })
 mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + './views/index.ejs');
```

Comment: Have you considered going the PWA route?  https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/desktop

Comment: thanks @Brad...I will try it but need to know more help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to continue using server-side views with Electron.  But there is no true server in that environment (although technically you could create one - spin off an express server listening on a port and have the front end "browse" to it).

What you should look into is client side EJS template processing.  It is pretty simple if it is all views.  A bigger question will arise if you are also trying to get the data for the view from the same server side application.  In that case you have a pretty big change to undertake - getting the node server code into the Electron main process and passing it back/forth with the renderer.   At that point the "embedded" express server idea starts looking worth it.